# split at space and non-digit... include non-digit delimiter, don't include space delimiter

Tags: ruby, regex

trying to program a calculator in ruby, i'd like to put everything into an array so that i can gsub out words for math symbols.

```
answer ||= 0
puts "CALCULATE"
puts "#{answer}"
input = gets.chomp.split(/([\s\D])/) 

# for test
puts "response #{input}"
puts "asdf" unless input.is_a? Array
puts "qwer array inputs: #{input.length}"
```

researching it forever, many many thanks

looking for

```
8*15 => ["8", "*", "15"]
eight times 15 => ["eight", "times", "15"]
8 divided by 15 => ["8", "divided", "by", "15"]
```

Comment: maybe `split(/[\s\b]/)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```
re = /\s+|([^\d\s]+)/
puts "8*15".split(re).reject { |c| c.empty? }
```

See the [IDEONE demo](https://ideone.com/O3un75)

The `\s+` matches 1 or more whitespace symbols (and they will be removed as we do not capture this subpattern) and `([^\d\s]+)` will match and *capture* 1+ symbols other than a digit and whitespace, and will be output since it is captured.

With `.reject { |c| c.empty? }`, we get rid of empty elements inside the resulting array.

Comment: crazy.   so i'm readying that as split at one or more whitespace, OR at one or more of anything other than digits/whitespace (... which leaves letters or %*-/ type), and capture the other than digit/whitespace.     why not use \D\S?    thank you very much

Comment: You cannot use just \D because that would split on each nondigit (if you add \S? than one or zero nonwhitespace will also be consumed during the split).

Comment: A ``\`` + some letters may denote a shorthand character class, but not any letter. `\T` does not denote any shorthand character class. `\d` matches a digit. See more at [Shorthand Character Classes](http://www.regular-expressions.info/shorthand.html).

Comment: ya, i meant i could use \w or \W or \D instead of the \d, still works the same.   i failed to wrap my head around the concept and moved on.

Answer (score 0):

Wiktor's answer is good, but here's an alternative for the sake of completeness:

```
expr = /[\S&&\D]+|\d+/

p "8*15".scan(expr)
# => ["8", "*", "15"]

p "eight times 15".scan(expr)
# => ["eight", "times", "15"]

p "eight divided by 15".scan(expr)
# => ["eight", "divided", "by", "15"]
```

Instead of splitting the string, this uses `String#scan` to return the matching parts of the string. Here's the regular expression dissected:

```
expr = /
  [\S&&\D]+ # One or more characters that is neither whitespace nor a digit
  |         # ...or...
  \d+       # One or more digits
/x
```

In case it's unfamiliar, `&&` in a [character class](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.0/Regexp.html#class-Regexp-label-Character+Classes) is the set intersection operator. `\S` is the set of all non-whitespace characters and `\D` is the set of all non-digit characters, so `[\S&&\D]` matches any character that is neither whitespace nor a digit.